salt pkgrepo.managed appending a new line on every run
I've defined a pkgrepo.managed state in my salt files. On every run of salt, it is adding an additional - and identical - line in the sources.list.d directory, resulting in an apt error. A google found another post with the same situation, but no solution.
newrelic-infrastructure-repo:
    pkgrepo.managed:
      - humanname: Newrelic Infrastructure Agent
      - name: deb https://download.newrelic.com/infrastructure_agent/linux/apt xenial main
      - dist: stable
      - file: /etc/apt/sources.list.d/newrelic-infrastructure.list
      - require_in:
        - pkg: newrelic-infra-pkg
      - gpgcheck: 1
      - key_url: https://download.newrelic.com/infrastructure_agent/gpg/newrelic-infra.gpg

I declared this in my .sls file and applied I expected /etc/apt/sources.list.d/newrelic-infrastructure.list to contain a single line. However, after several runs my file has multiple lines:
staging-i-0e4fb7971dd8c0f05:/etc/apt/sources.list.d$ cat newrelic-infrastructure.list
deb https://download.newrelic.com/infrastructure_agent/linux/apt stable main
deb https://download.newrelic.com/infrastructure_agent/linux/apt stable main
deb https://download.newrelic.com/infrastructure_agent/linux/apt stable main
deb https://download.newrelic.com/infrastructure_agent/linux/apt stable main
deb https://download.newrelic.com/infrastructure_agent/linux/apt stable main
deb https://download.newrelic.com/infrastructure_agent/linux/apt stable main
deb https://download.newrelic.com/infrastructure_agent/linux/apt stable main


"another post with the same situation" - link?

Probably because you're defining conflicting properties. Delete the - dist: stable and then change xenial to stable.
humanname also does nothing for apt repositories.
Basically, the examples in the docs are bad.

@OrangeDog had the right idea. Once I corrected my values in the yaml, and deleted the erroneous file, it succeeded and installed correctly.
It seems that any failures to complete the state will result in a new line being added on supsequent state.apply runs. Bug?
Working state:
newrelic-infrastructure-repo:
  pkgrepo.managed:
    - name: deb https://download.newrelic.com/infrastructure_agent/linux/apt xenial main
    - file: /etc/apt/sources.list.d/newrelic-infrastructure.list
    - require_in:
      - pkg: newrelic-infra-pkg
    - gpgcheck: 1
    - key_url: https://download.newrelic.com/infrastructure_agent/gpg/newrelic-infra.gpg

